# docker-compose running entrypoint script in another directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I was just wondering how to run a docker-entrypoint script in another directory. For example,

```
the-service:
   image: the-service
   container_name: the-service
   entrypoint: ./app/the/docker-entrypoint.sh 
   build: ./app/the
   ports:
     - 8080:8080
```

here I get 
`ERROR: for the-service  Cannot start service the-service: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"./app/the-service/docker-entrypoint.sh\": stat ./app/the-service/docker-entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.`

docker-compose version is 2.1.
So what is the correct way of running this script?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have figured it out.
You are using the build option so that the docker image can live inside the docker-compose project.
This is a little non-standard, but perfectly OK.
Using image is more standard.

The entrypoint is executed after the build, regardless of the position in the docker-compose.yml file.
When we write the entrypoint, we are writing a reference to a file in the image not the local file system.

You should probably edit your .app/the/Dockerfile as follows
add "COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /"
add "ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

Then you can edit your docker-compose.yml by removing the "entrypoint: ./app/the/docker-entrypoint.sh"

---

OLD ANSWER

Without testing it out myself, I would assume that these would work:

1. As @B0rn2C0de suggest set the workdir appropriately.
2. Alternatively, use a relative path to where the WORKDIR actually is
3. Alternatively, use an absolute path.

Comment: Can I set the workdir in docker-compose? entrypoint will be run before building. So I think that setting WORKDIR in dockerfile wouldn't work. @B0rn2C0de

Comment: @yuzir - your comment confuses me.  https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir shows how to set the workdir in docker-compose.  entrypoint is run after building regardless of the order in docker-compose.yml

Comment: @yuzir - I think I have figured out the mistake you are making.  See edits to my answer.

Comment: you are right! thank you. It worked. Sorry for the unclear comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the current working directory to your app's location in your docker file using the `WORKDIR` options
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir